# Unable to get the right sessions count using Bigquery standard SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform, google-analytics-api

I want to get the total sessions but just because I am unnesting 'hit.product' and 'hits' at same time as shown in the below code, its giving me less session count than that I can see in GA. I am suspecting that it is filtering out the sessions that doesn't have any products.

There is also a way that i can handle that without using unnest by using Array as shown below

```
ARRAY(SELECT DISTINCT v2ProductCategory FROM UNNEST(hits.product)) AS v2ProductCategory
```

Is there any way if I can pull all the sessions and its product category, product name and hits info(hits.time, hits.page.pagepath) without using ARRAY which I would be using it in my further analysis?

```
select count(distinct session) from(SELECT
   fullvisitorid,
   CONCAT(CAST(fullVisitorId AS string),CAST(visitId AS string)) AS session,
   hits.time,
   hits.page.pagePath,
   hits.eCommerceAction.action_type,
   product.v2ProductCategory,
   product.v2ProductName
  FROM
    `XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX`,
      UNNEST(hits) AS hits,
    UNNEST(hits.product) AS product
  WHERE
    _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN "20170930"
    AND "20170930")
```

Comment: are you sure your `hits.product` is a repeated record?! i thought it should be just a record - which mean you shouldn't `UNNEST` it! but rather treat it as a `STRUCT`

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant As per Big query schema. hits.product is mentioned as 'record'
https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3437719?hl=en

Comment: no doubt - it is a record. the point in my comment was - is it NULLABLE or REPEATED record. You should check your table schema in BigQuery UI. The link you provided misses this info!

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant I just now checked. The record is 'REPEATED'.

Comment: ok. so you are good with UNNEST then. just wanted to check as somehow I thought this one is a NULLABLE :o)

Comment: You're not going to get a row in the output if `hits.product` is empty. Use LEFT JOIN instead of the comma operator with UNNEST.

Comment: @ElliottBrossard Thanks this helps